# How to position a checkbox before the list item markers

Tags: css

Background:
I have a list of items and each item has a checkbox for disabling/enabling.
I also put ordered numbers in front of the text

And there's also some *changable state* unrelated to the checkbox toggling

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Special text
    <span style="color:green;">True (changable state)</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

*How do I position the checkbox before the list item marker (ordered numbers)?*

---

**Note:**
While I was explaining how it seemed impossible; I figured it out, see my answer below.
And I mentioned the (changable state) to explain why I didn't want to place the checkbox to the right of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
   position: absolute; /* Also removes element from document flow */
   left: 0; /* Place at the left of its containing element */
}

ol {
   position: relative; /*
      This magic line seems to do nothing, but
      for `absolute`ly positioned elements,
      the containing element is the nearest parent
      whose position is not `static`.

      The left of the <li> doesn't work (see purple border)
      so naturally the <ol> gets the position: relative;
      since it contains some space before the li::marker
   */
   
   padding-left: 3em; /* Hardcoded space */
   border-left: 2px solid orange;
}

li {
   border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Special text
    <span style="color:green;">True (changable state)</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

MDN `absolute` position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values
MDN containing block: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block

Wonderfully this solution is also helpful for any other element you'd like to place before the marker